# Empty request payload when saving new record - Ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

## What I'm Trying:

Persist a new record but for some reason the request payload is empty even though the record has data.

*Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brancusi/m8VrB/16/*

*(Disregard the firebase, it's just there so we can inspect the request payload on save.)*

## Explanation:

You will notice that when you save the record, the request payload is empty.

Ideally the request payload would look something like this:

```
{
    "inventory": {
        "entry_time": "2014-02-05",
        "client_id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "product_stock_levels": [
            {
                "product_id": 1,
                "quantity": 2
            },
            {
                "product_id": 2,
                "quantity": 0
            },
            {
                "product_id": 3,
                "quantity": 8
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

## Notes:

This only seems to be a problem when it's a new record. Updating existing records send the correct payload.

Comment: Should have maybe added instructions. Just submit the form and watch the network activity. Also, notice the console log, the quantities come out correctly, so the data is there.

Comment: Made a fork for this fiddle that adds a prop to the record and that is in the payload, so the issue is really just with the "hasMany" records. http://jsfiddle.net/brancusi/MLkRV/8/

Comment: So far I'm having to do this in two steps. I save the parent record and in the promise->then I save the the child set. In total though it makes around 10 calls to the server when using real data. This would really not scale well, 20-30 products eventually in one pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting ember data to embed relationships in a model on save as default. This is not the default behavior.

You could define relationships as being embedded per model. But there is no support for embedded record feature anymore as stated here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md I am not sure if basic embedded record features still work with latest version of ember data. But you define a record as embedded like this:

```
App.InventorySerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {
        productStockLevels: {embedded: 'always'}
    }
});
```

Because core team stopped support for this embedded records feature and it is very basic I would recommend you to use `EmbbededAdapter` or `EmbeddedMixin` if you need support for embedded records. You find them here: https://github.com/pixelhandler/ember-data-extensions

But as Ember Data EmbeddedAdapter is not stable yet. Perhaps you should consider not to embedded records to reduce complexity if you are flexible in defining the api.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried to add this to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brancusi/9ZAbr/4/ It doesn't seem to change the payload. I've been reading the transition log you linked and it sounds like that is for deserialization. I would even be totally fine with not embedding the child records, but rather creating a payload similar to sideloading a request. As long as I can somehow submit the whole form in one go so I can process everything on the server side correctly. Basically the same payload as when you Update a record.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Did not used build in embedded record support for a longer time. I fixed the answer. P.S.: The response of your server is wrong. That is why you are getting an error when server responds.

Comment: Nice that worked: http://jsfiddle.net/brancusi/9ZAbr/5/ Thanks so much. This is a nice option to have. I was doing this manually with a custom serializer, but it somehow messed with the rest of the records coming in. Thanks for the quick response!